# Etymology of Pine Street in San Francisco

Tags: california

In San Francisco, California, what is Pine Street named after?

Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologies_of_place_names_in_San_Francisco and other internet sources about SF street naming do not give any information regarding this street naming.

Comment: Trivia is off topic.

Comment: I would think it is named because of pine trees but I cannot find any evidence or even mention in history books.

Comment: That would probably be a good guess. An even better guess is that there was originally a pine tree at the corner.

Comment: Not even that. Often a city planner will name a series of parallel streets in a neighborhood with a common theme - so if the theme was trees, you could have Pike, Oak, Elm, Ash as blocks without reference to any real tree.  I've seen State names, Civil War Battles used like this, and of course numbers as well.

Comment: Looking at the map, I see parallel streets in SFO to Pine with names Bush, Fern, Hemlock, Cedar, Myrtle, Olive, Willow, Larch and Elm.  This fits my theory of city planning.

Comment: It is naïve to assume that because there is an object named a *pine* that the street is necessarily named after it - more likely is that the street is named after a *Pine* (person) than a *pine*. For example, numerous *Hill Street*'s throughout the British Empire are nowhere near a hill - being named after the Major General Hill who seconded Wellington at Waterloo rather than any geographical landmark.

Comment: And there must be hundreds of "Rembrandt street"s in the Netherlands where the painter never could have visited let alone lived simply because the towns (or the streets) didn't exist while the man was alive.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens "Hill" is vastly more common as a surname than "Pine". i agree with Oldcat's theory about thematically named streets, a common device.

Answer (score 1):

Pine Street, Pine Lake, Laurel...I say nature. As for the streets named after people, I would reference this:http://www.sfgenealogy.com/sf/history/hgstr.htm
;-)